# How to run Row_Number() with filtering

Tags: sql, t-sql, row-number

I have a table with multiple rows for each 'Case Number'. I want to pick one row for each Case Number and join this back to another table maintaining a one-to-one relationship.

The conditions to pick this row are :

1) First of all filter out all rows for each Case Number that have Stage = Cancelled

2) If you find Stage = 'In Progress' or 'Paused', pick that row. (Only one of these two can be present for a Case Number)

3) If not (2), then pick Stage = 'Completed' but for the latest 'Stop Time'. (This is where I thought we might have to use ROW_NUMBER())

I've already created a query to push in row numbers and pick up one row based on the latest 'Stop time' but I'm not able to figure out how to add the above filters and if-else conditions in there.

```
    SELECT  [Case Number],
ROW_NUMBER ( )  
    OVER ( PARTITION BY [Case Number] order by [Stop time] desc )  idx
      ,[Stage]
      ,[Time left]
      ,[SLA definition]
      ,[Elapsed time]
      ,[Elapsed percentage]
      ,[Start time]
      ,[Stop time]
      ,[Has breached]
      ,[Breach time]
      ,[Updated]
      ,[Updated by]
      ,[Created]
      ,[Created by]


  FROM ( select * from [SLA_Data] where Stage != 'Cancelled' )v1
```

Comment: Your query is pretty far off, and your question would be easier to understand if we could see some sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I've posted the latest query I've been able to write which is satisfying condition number 1. Unfortunately, I cannot post any data since this is confidential data.

Comment: Well maybe reconsider that decision, because other than the complete lack of data, it seems like an interesting question.

Comment: Have you considered the dense_rank() function? ROW_NUMBER will provide an increment for each instance found of the partition specified, where as if you use dense_rank()over(order by task order) then you should see a unique incremental entry per taskorder.

Comment: Why Case Number is missing in your select statement?

Comment: Apologies, 'Task' was actually 'Case Number'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell from your question but something like this is my interpretation (I'm not able to access SQL, nor did you provide enough test data so cannot test it)

```
   select * from
    ( 
    SELECT  [Task],...,...,
    ROW_NUMBER ( )      
    OVER ( PARTITION BY Task order by 
        case 
        when Stage in('In Progress' ,'Paused') then 1
        when Stage='Completed' then 2 end,
        [Stop time] desc )  idx
    ) 
    where idx=1
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine, I'm in the middle of verifying the data. Can you please tell me what the '1' and '2' are doing after 'then' in the 'case' statement?

Comment: They are giving you something to order by.  If it's in progress or paused then 1, completed 2.  Order by that number.  It's a way to simply turn your exotic order requirements into something simple.  If you still don't get it, you can put the `CASE` to a similar `SELECT` statement as well to see what's going on.

Comment: Is it working in the sense that it is ordering by two things at once? First by Stage and then by Stop Time? 
It's giving me the correct results but would love to have a very clear picture of how it is working.

Comment: Correct. Your in progress & paused will also have the secondary sort by stop time - I assume that doesn't matter.

Comment: It doesn't! Awesome!
I have another question for you though. What if out of these tickets, I want to filter out the ones where all entries for 'Start time' are the same. How do I implement that here?

Comment: you can try to add another window function `count(distinct start_time) over (partition by ... <whatever makes sense for the groups of "same start"...> ) as countStarts` then `where idx=1 and CountStarts>1`.  That's a bit of a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work assuming **Case_Number** is present in the below table or the present table must be joined with the **Case_Number** Table

```
create view [dbo].[SLA_View] as select * from (

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT  [Task]
      ,[Stage]
      ,[Time left]
      ,[SLA definition]
      ,[Elapsed time]
      ,[Elapsed percentage]
      ,[Start time]
      ,[Stop time]
      ,[Has breached]
      ,[Breach time]
      ,[Updated]
      ,[Updated by]
      ,[Created]
      ,[Created by]
FROM
(
/* GETS SINGLE CASE FOR MULTIPLE STAGES */
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER ( )  OVER ( PARTITION BY Task order by [Stage] desc)  RNK
 FROM [SLA_Data] WHERE [CASE_NUMBER] IN 
(
/* GETS DISTINCT CASE NUMBER WITH STAGE = 'PAUSED' OR 'IN PROGRESS' */
SELECT DISTINCT [CASE_NUMBER]
  FROM [SLA_Data]
  WHERE [Stage] != 'Cancelled'
  AND [Stage] IN ('Paused','In Progess')
  GROUP BY  [CASE_NUMBER]
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
  )
  )Y
  WHERE RNK = 1
)Z
UNION
SELECT [Task]
      ,[Stage]
      ,[Time left]
      ,[SLA definition]
      ,[Elapsed time]
      ,[Elapsed percentage]
      ,[Start time]
      ,[Stop time]
      ,[Has breached]
      ,[Breach time]
      ,[Updated]
      ,[Updated by]
      ,[Created]
      ,[Created by]
      FROM
      (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER ( )  OVER ( PARTITION BY Task order by [start time] desc)  idx
      FROM [SLA_Data]
      WHERE [CASE_NUMBER] NOT IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT [CASE_NUMBER]
  FROM [SLA_Data]
  WHERE [Stage] != 'Cancelled'
  AND [Stage] IN ('Paused','In Progess')
  GROUP BY  [CASE_NUMBER]
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
)v1 where idx = 1
)
```